# Firefox context menu: different render method

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, contextmenu

So this is a rather specific question I feel. I want to be able to pre-load the Firefox context menu. I'd like this to happen each time a new tab and/or window is opened. I want the menu and all its associated items to be rendered upon such a request, but I don't want the menu to open as well.

And just to preface, I have e-mailed the developers of OneTab about this, no reply.

(This next section's a bit rambly, but it does explain how I came to the above question).

> To contextualise why I'd like to do this: I use an addon called OneTab. It's an awesome addon (and this isn't a plug, just what I think). It can transfer some/all of your current tabs in Firefox into a singular tab for reviewing etc later. So each time you send a bunch of tabs into OneTab, it creates a new group for them. You can name these groups too which I like to do. Helps stay organised. I habitually create a lot of tabs when I'm browsing. So I've also got a lot of tab groups. Now another feature is OneTab's context menu. This is pretty much the method by which you send tabs to OneTab. Now once you've created tab groups, you can then send future tabs to those groups, via the context menu. 
>
>
>  Rendering all those options each time the menu is opened on a new tab, takes about 3 seconds for me at the moment. It also stops me interacting with any part of Firefox for that time. Here's an example of the (current) menu structure. [Example of OneTab menu structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QznhJ.jpg). At the top right of the menu structure, where it says "Surge protection", there are 4 sub-menu headings. This is the case for all the other tab groups. So that's a lot of entries to render at once. I'm not surprised it takes a while.
>
>
>  One other thing: after I've loaded the context menu once (on the particular tab I'm on), it's just there. The next time I right-click it loads instantly, which is what I want to happen in the first place!!

So this is why I'm asking if it's possible to change the behaviour of the context menu from the Firefox source code. So that all the items are pre-rendered each time a new tab/window is created, but the menu is still opened normally via a right-click. And I think I'd like to utilise Workers for this. Because I know that Workers are background. They don't prevent user interaction. And that's exactly what happens currently, for 3 seconds. And if there's a way of doing this via an addon then so much the better. Whatever works!

Does this all make sense somewhat? I'm sorry if I've broken any formatting rules or something by posting such a long and wordy question! Just thought I might as well be detailed.

Comment: Why are you asking to change the design of Firefox when the problem is clearly and obviously the fault of the extension you have loaded? Provide this feedback to the add-on designer. Submit a Request for Enhancement (RFE) with the add-on designer. In other words, if their add-on is slowing down Firefox, then they should fix their add-on (multiple posible solutions).

Comment: This is clearly *way* too broad a question for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Well as I said, I already have fed this back to them and it has decidedly been ignored. Okay, well next time I'll try be more specific. Sorry this is my first ever post!

Comment: OK. I didn't see that you had already made that request of the add-on authors. How long have you given them to respond? You may be SOL. Most add-ons are released under a open source license, but this one is not. Thus, while I would normally suggest that you fix the add-on yourself, that is not permitted. If you have given them a reasonable amount of time to respond: leave a review that is less than 5 star and mention the problem in the review so other people know it is an issue with the add-on.

Comment: Your question appears to be: is it "possible to change the behaviour of the context menu from the Firefox source code"?. The answer is "Yes". If you are really asking how to do it, then the question is too broad for Stack Overflow.  Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [ask] and "How to create a [mcve]".

Comment: Yeah it's been 2 and half months. Alright yeah I might just leave a review then. So to modify the addon, even if it's just for personal use, is illegal? 

And yes I guess that was what I was asking. So I'll post another (more specific) question if and when I'm further down the line with modifying the context menu behaviour.

Comment: (In the USA): From a legal standpoint, there is a significant difference between all of "unlawful", "illegal", "criminal", and "violation of copyright". For most things, violating a copyright is a civil (between you and the copyright holder), not a criminal issue. One of the rights that is part of the copyright is the right to create derivative works. Modifying the add-on would be creating a derivative work, even if it is for personal use. Thus, while doing so might be possible, and some people would choose to do so, it is inappropriate for me to advocate (suggest) doing so.